# Request to external sites: client or server side?

Tags: ajax, node.js, architecture, request

I'm working on a site that depends on another site for data access.  There are places where it makes sense to make the request from the client side, and others where it only makes sense do it on the server side.

My question is, in general, is it more advisable (in terms of performance, scalability, etc.) to lean more towards sending/receiving requests for *external* resources from the server rather than the client, or is the difference negligible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what these *external resources* are what you plan to do with them.

For example, if you are displaying a PDF hosted externally, then you cannot have a functionality that prints the PDF (I mean an explicit trigger - the user can make use of the PDF controls if his browser has one, but you cannot explicitly trigger print) because of [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). In such cases, it makes more sense to first fetch the external PDF from the server and then pass it on to the client.

There are also those cases where you fetch certain resources from your server and certain resource externally. In such cases, there could exist a scenario where your server is not responding properly or the server hosting the external resource has gone down. Parts of your application will work while parts will not - which does not lead to a good user experience.
If you directly use the external resource, then you will have lesser control over this scenario - your server on the other hand will be able to elegantly degrade to a better resource in case of failures.

It all boils down on the kind of resources you plan to work with. You are the best judge since you have a better knowledge of what you plan to do.